# Undefined Function confusing

Tags: python

I have this bit of code here, and I was wondering why I was getting "total_with_tax is undefined"

This happens when I do:

```
c = Customer()
c.print_bill() --> this is where I get the error
```

**Code:**

```
class Customer:
def __init__(self):
    self.total = 0
    self.items_ordered = str("")

def add_to_order(self, NameOfItem, CostOfItem):
    self.total += CostOfItem
    self.items_ordered = self.items_ordered + (str(NameOfItem) + ", ")

def total_with_tax(self):
    return ((self.total * 0.13) + self.total)

def print_bill(self):
    print("----------------------------------------------")
    print(self.items_ordered)
    print("$%d" %(self.total))
    print("$%d" %(total_with_tax()))
    print("----------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: Your indentation is all off. That matters a lot in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prefix `total_with_tax` with `self`, like this:

```
 print("$%d" % self.total_with_tax())
```